# Stereo setup with autofocus webcams in opencv

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, camera-calibration

I do have a stereo setup with two webcams. The question is will there be any problem if those cameras possess auto-focus technology. If yes, please specify the problems in detail along with its solutions.

Does that effect on the camera calibration?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Autofocus will have an effect on the calibration because with low quality lenses the change in focus will also change the focal length and the optical center.

There isn't much you can do about this - but since you are only working with simple webcams there probably isn't much need to worry about it since you are going to have limited accuracy anyway.

Comment: Thanks of answering my question. Well my research is on 3D reconstruction/recognition. What kind of inaccuracy I can have. On what basis does that limited accuracy is occurring.

Comment: Your accuracy is ultimately limited by the camera calibration and camera signal/noise. Try it - you may be surprised how well you can do with even simple systems

Answer (score 1):

Yes, to my knowledge offcourse there will certainly be a problem with autofocus cameras.

With the change in the focal length the camera parameters changes. Thereby, it is always a problem with cameras having autofocus.

Certainly, it will effect the camera calibration.